# Can I change company's name in quote from before the name was legally changed?

Tags: quotes

So in one of my reports I am quoting an executive who talks about the company "Company X" at a time when it was still called "Company X." This was a few months ago, and the company's name has since been changed to "Company Z." Can I change the company name to the current name in the executive's quoted sentence?

Comment: Is the name of Company X all that changed? Is it literally the  same company with a different name.  You'd probably want to go with the original name, because the executive was speaking  as executive of Company X. Company Z might not literally bet he same legal entity.

Comment: You might want to make it unambiguous that the executive worked at the old company too.

Answer (score 1):

The usual practice if it is necessary to make a change to a quote is to put the change in square brackets. Example:

> Jones wrote "In all my years working at Company X [now named Company Y] I've never heard of such a thing."